# How to Access the UIView of the Container

Tags: ios, swift, uicontainerview

If I'm currently inside of the ViewController that is inside of a container, how can I access the restoration id of the view. So if I'm currently in the ViewController of the view that is inside of the container. How can I access the restoration id that is in the picture that says "topView" I've tried all these options (most of the options I didn't expect to work, but I've been trying everything):

```
print(self.view.window?.rootViewController?.restorationIdentifier)
print(self.view.window?.restorationIdentifier)
print(self.view.window?.superview!.restorationIdentifier)
print(self.view.restorationIdentifier)
print(self.parent?.view.restorationIdentifier)
```

These all print nil

[image: Shows where I'm working with restoration id]

Comment: Self.parent?.view.subviews[0].resto...

Comment: print(self.parent) AND 
print(self.parent?.view.subviews[0].restorationIdentifier) both print nil as well

Answer (score -1):

You need to find which one is the container UIView.

```
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(animated)

  print(self.parent?.view.subviews)
 // There are two subviews in this case. The last one is the container view. Your case may be different.

  print  ((self.parent?.view.subviews[0]) )
  print (((self.parent?.view.subviews[1]) as! UIView).restorationIdentifier)
}
```